# How do hosts filter broadcast signals in wireless network?

Tags: wireless, mac-address, mac

In bus/hub network, hosts check the destination address of every broadcasted packet they receive and accept it if they are the destination, otherwise they ignore it. Do we use the same principle in wireless network?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In all shared media, every host receives every frame.  The host determines which are addressed for it and ignores everything else.

In switched Ethernet, the switch only sends packets to the host that match its address(es), but the host still acts as if it's a shared media, *i.e.,* it only responds to frames addressed to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But what im asking is if that same principle used in shared wired network also applies to wireless network. So are you confirming it when you say "In all shared media.."?

Comment: Wireless is a shared media.  Every radio (in range) hears every transmission.